# Power Bi: Calculate sum of columns month wise in other table

Tags: powerbi

I have the leave data of a company. 
 Here is the sample data:

```
STAFF  PL   CL  ML  SP  LWP TL  Month
A      1    2   0   0   6   9   April
B      14   0   4   0   0   18  April
A      1    2   0   0   1   4   May
B      1    0   4   0   0   5   May
A      1    2   0   0   2   5   June
B      2    0   4   0   0   6   June
```

I want to transform this data into a table structure like this-

Here is the sample data:

```
Types of Leave  Count   Month
ML                89    4
CL                114   4
LWP               17    4
PL                135   4
SP                89    4
ML                89    5
CL                114   5
LWP               17    5
PL                135   5
SP                89    5
ML                89    6
CL                114   6
LWP               17    6
PL                135   6
SP                89    6
```

Can it be possible using SelectColumns, Summarizecolumn dax functions?

I tried --

```
SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[CL],Table1[LWP],Table1[ML],Table1[PL],"CL2", SUM(Table1[CL]), "ML2", SUM(Table1[ML]), "LW2P",SUM(Table1[LWP]), "P2L", SUM(Table1[PL]))
```

It just gave me weird results.

Comment: If the top data is your source, it looks to me that you need to remove the TL and the Name column, and then unpivot the data. Transform the Month name to month number and then you can use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the data after removing the name and the staff columns. Then convert the month name to the month number and build a pivot table.

The screenshot shows the result in Excel, but the same can be done in Power BI.

[image]

Here is the M code for the query as it was recorded when I clicked the ribbon icons:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"STAFF", type text}, {"PL", Int64.Type}, {"CL", Int64.Type}, {"ML", Int64.Type}, {"SP", Int64.Type}, {"LWP", Int64.Type}, {"TL", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"STAFF", "TL"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Month"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Type of Leave"}, {"Value", "Count"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each Date.FromText([Month]&"1 2017")),
    #"Extracted Month" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", Date.Month}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Month",{"Month"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Custom", "Month"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```